# Collect Data from two fields, to input into a complete list

Tags: excel, list, return-value

I have been working on this document, I have been going to YouTube to learn how to do some of these things for myself. I hate asking for help because sometimes I never learn how to do things myself.

So I am looking at this one script in "lesson" 358, the concept of the lesson is to make it so that the script references one point of reference to get the information in question.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tp7I5...feature=relmfu

The problem with this video is that although it is well done he really isn't referencing one field. He is using multiple fields and calling it one reference point.

That is the video, here is the attachment document to the video is here.

[Download Excel Sheet from Video](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://people.highline.edu/mgirvin/YouTubeExcelIsFun/EMT358-369.xls&ei=C7h0T_TUKKPh0gH6x73_Ag&usg=AFQjCNFxd8l9ds8ixYz8QWODC_8oEtLgZA&sig2=Fh2BpycfGPnMEER4Sc9fHQ)

What I wanted to do was to have it so the script only reference one point of interest, so I emailed the creator of the script, and he told me that he can't help. Sounds more like he didn't want to help...

Here is my file, What I am attempting to do is this:

[My Excel Sheet](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Calandar.xlsx)

In AH1 I have a date, that I am using as the reference point for the entire formula that I thought I could use.

And have done so successfully in the AJ2 Script...

What I wanted to do is to make my document utilize the script in the lesson above but with one reference point instead of two in AK2 downwards... The list it is pulling data from in this case is Topic1.

What ends up happening is that I try to cut out the reference point is it tells me that there are too few references and won't let me save the script.

I have attempted several times to get this working, but for some reason it's causing me issues, well that seems to be nothing new.

And if the creator of the script can't help me, I know I'm not going to be able to do it myself, even though I've spend the last two days trying...

Can someone help me here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Fix AH1.   Just put in the formula **=TODAY()** and then format the cell the same way you formatted cell AA4.

2) Fix AJ2.   The formula should be:  **=COUNTIF(AA4:AA23,AH1)**

3) Fix AK2.   The *array* formula should be:
**=IF(ROW($A1)>$AJ$2, "", INDEX(AB$1:AB$23, SMALL(IF(AA$1:AA$23=Criteria, ROW($AA$1:$AA$23), ""), ROW($A1))))**

...confirmed by pressing *CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER*, then copy that cell down a ways, multiple values can appear now if needed.

[image]

Comment: I get an error #VALUE.  The part:

AA$1:AA$23 is underline... it seems it doesn't like it.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to confirm it, now I come back with a 0, even though I changed the date to show today...

Comment: From the picture above you see the formula does work.  How does your differ from mine in item 3) ?   If you do not correct the AH1 it won't work either.  AH1 has to exactly match the values in AA.  Post a new file if you want me to troubleshoot the formulas you've entered.

Comment: Here is the new file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Calandar2.xlsx 

For some reason it is exactly as yours shows, as far as I can tell. Perhaps I am missing something, like a comma somewhere, but I don't think so.  Thanks for the help again.

Comment: fix the formula in AJ2 as instructed originally, it's NOT a countifS, it's just a CountIf.   Then fix the array formula back to EXACTLY what I gave above.  You edited it to start at row4 instead of Row1.  I know the data is in row4, but I don't want to add to the formula to offset the row/match differential, so we just start at row1.

Comment: The reason I moved the array is because I am going to be using said formula in all 5 topics, if it doesn't fit correctly into each section then I can't use the formula because it will allow or cause overlap, which I can't have. Sorry, but I'll give kudos to some parts of it, but not the answer as a whole because it doesn't do what was requested entirely.

Comment: I was referring to keeping the range starting at row1, even though you don't need it to.  Doing so makes the formula easier to write. When i fixed the formulas back to as described it works.  You'll have to further present what doesn't work.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/excel/Calandar3.xlsx  This is what is happening. Instead of the topic, 0 is showing. I need it the way it is so that I can transfer the code to other lists without bleedover.

Comment: I keep directing you to the same fix.  You changed the function range to **AB$4:AB$23** and I know why you did, but you need to change all those "4"s back to "1"s and it works fine.  It's an edit you shouldn't make.  We are matching to the ROW so we just need to start the count at row1, not row4, even though 1-3 will never be a match.  **=IF(ROW($A1)>$AJ$2, "", INDEX(AB$1:AB$23, SMALL(IF(AA$1:AA$23=Criteria, ROW($AA$1:$AA$23), ""), ROW($A1))))**  That's the formula from step #3 of this answer and it still works, every time I put it in as shown.

Comment: Ok, I have done what you said, and it works.  But why? Why not make it in the fields instead of go to the top like that?

Comment: that array formula is complex as it is.  If you start your ranges in row4, then you would need to adjust your use of the ROW() function in several places and the formula just gets more confusing.  I use the SMALL(IF()) trick anytime I need multiple results from a single INDEX, but I always start the search ranges at row1 to keep the formula as short as possible.  Personal preference.

Comment: Question, how would you do the script then? I'm just curious...in other words how would you make it from scratch?

Comment: What are we talking about now?  This is getting long for comments, click on my name and we can discuss further by email if you wish.

Comment: How? I looked and didn't see the way to do it.